error deploying tabular cube to Power BI: duplicate member
I am trying to deploy a tabular cube from Visual Studio to Power BI (Premium).  I am encountering the following deployment error message:

Cannot deploy metadata.  Reason: Failed to save modifications to the server.  Error returned: 'M Engine error: 'Microsoft.Data.Mashup.Preview; This document contains a duplicate member 'Dates'.

How can I resolve this error?  There is only 1 instance of the Dates table in my cube.
